# MenuItems contributed by fragment.e4xmi are not being translated, contributorURI is missing

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, eclipse-rcp

I have a strange problem with my Eclipse 4 RCP application which sometimes does not translate some menu items due to a missing `contributorURI`.

## Situation

I'm currently working on an Eclipse 4 RCP application which consists of multiple localized plugins.

One of those plugins is `com.mobatime.nms.masterclock.common.ui`. Its `fragment.e4xmi` contributes some localized `MenuItems` to the main menu bar which is "controlled" by the `Application.e4xmi` of another plugin (`com.mobatime.nms.app`). With localized I mean that the `MenuItem`'s label is a `OSGI` variable (e.g. `%commands.somecommand`) that is defined in an `OSGI-INF/l10n/bundle.properties` file.

However, **on about 50% of all starts of my application, the `MenuItems` contributed by the `masterclock` plugin are not being translated**, so that the name of the `OSGI` variable is used as the label for the `MenuItem`.

## Things I already found out

- After some research on the internet, I found [this thread](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/309562/) which apparently describes a problem relatively similar to mine. The thread, however, is already five years old and the described bug they found was fixed in an older version of the Eclipse SDK.
- I imported the ModelSpy plugin into my application since it helped to find the bug in the thread I mentioned above. After inspecting the `MenuItems` **I found out that the `contributorURI` of each item is not set** when the translation is missing.
- When the translation is done correctly, the `contributerURI` of a contributed `MenuItem` contains `platform:/plugin/com.mobatime.nms.masterclock.common.ui`.

## Additional information

- We use the newest version of the Eclipse libraries (SDK, RCP etc.).
- The problem also occurres on an older version of these libraries (we used version 4.4.2 earlier).
- There's no difference between regular builds and debug sessions in the Eclipse IDE, the error happens everywhere.
- **On other items, the `contributorURI` is being filled in correctly.**
- In the `workbench.xmi` file of the `org.eclipse.e4.workbench` metadata, the contributorURI is not being saved on the affected `MenuItems`.
- When using `-clearPersistedState`, the problem does not occur.

**Does anybody has an idea how this can be fixed?**

Comment: Are you using the persisted state so that the model is reloaded from the saved state or are you using `-clearPersistedState` to prevent this (so the model is built from the fragments each time)?

Comment: I'm not using `clearPersistedState`, but when I add it to my debug configuration, the problem does not occur anymore. Probably a bug in Eclipse's persistence logic?

Comment: You could look at the persisted state in the `workbench.xmi` file in the `org.eclipse.e4.workbench` metadata to see if the contributorURI is being saved or not.

Comment: The workbench file does not save the contributorURI for the affected `MenuItems`...

I added the new information to the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some further research and found out that, in my case, the problem is related to when the application starts and the application.e4xmi is loaded.

The contributorUri of the affected MenuItems is being saved correctly into that file (in contradiction to what I wrote in my initial post), however when the application model is loaded from the file the Uri is either not read correctly from the file or not set to the MenuItem.

My current workaround is to just set the contributorUri for the affected MenuItems manually on application startup. This is most likely not the best solution, but it works for now:

```
MTrimmedWindow trim = (MTrimmedWindow) modelService.find("your-window-id", application);
MMenu menu = (MMenu)modelService.find("your-menu-id", trim.getMainMenu());
if(menu != null) {
    for(MMenuElement item : menu.getChildren()) {
        if(item instanceof MHandledMenuItem && item.getElementId().contains("some-common-string-in-the-menuitem-id")) {
                item.setContributorURI("platform:/plugin/com.example.yourcontributingplugin");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this issue is still of relevance, but I had a similar problem and solved it without the need of a workaround: In my case it helped to set the apply-property in plugin-xml either to always or default. Before it was set to notexists

```
<extension
     id=*yourextensionid*
     point="org.eclipse.e4.workbench.model">
  <fragment
        uri="fragment.e4xmi">
  </fragment>
```

or

```
<extension
     id=*yourextensionid*
     point="org.eclipse.e4.workbench.model">
  <fragment
        apply="always"
        uri="fragment.e4xmi">
  </fragment>
```